# If $\phi=\frac12(1+\sqrt5)$ and $n=\frac11+\frac1{1+\phi}+\frac1{1+\phi+\phi^2}+\cdots$, then evaluate $\lfloor2n\rfloor+\lceil2n\rceil$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, contest-math, golden-ratio

The question is

> Given that $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Let $$n=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1+\phi}+\frac{1}{1+\phi+\phi^2}+\frac{1}{1+\phi+\phi^2+\phi^3}+\dots$$
> The value of $\lfloor2n\rfloor+\lceil2n\rceil$ is $\dots$

I tried to find a general pattern that might exist for the first few terms but was unable to find a pattern that might simplify the problem. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What does ceil and rceil functions mean???

Comment: There are many ways to simplify this expression of $n$, most of them using the properties of the golden ratio $\phi$. One that might work for you is $\phi^2=\phi+1$.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915456/simplifying-the-sum-of-powers-of-the-golden-ratio

Comment: Something interesting: $n=(\phi-1)\frac{\psi^{(0)}_{1/\phi}(1)-\log(\phi+1)}{-\log(\phi)}$ according to wolfram, where $\psi$ is the diagamma function

Answer (score 7):

We will use twice the identity $\phi^2=\phi+1$ in our computation below.

Since $1+\phi+\phi^2+\cdots+\phi^{k-1}=\frac{\phi^k-1}{\phi-1}$, we have
\begin{align*}
n&=1+\frac{\phi-1}{\phi^2-1}+\frac{\phi-1}{\phi^3-1}+\frac{\phi-1}{\phi^4-1}+\cdots\\
&>1+(\phi-1)\left(\frac1{\phi^2}+\frac1{\phi^3}+\cdots\right)=1+(\phi-1)\frac{1/\phi^2}{1-1/\phi}\\
&=1+\frac1\phi=\frac{\phi+1}{\phi}=\phi.
\end{align*}

On the other hand
\begin{align*}
n&=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1+\phi}+\frac{1}{1+\phi+\phi^2}+\frac{1}{1+\phi+\phi^2+\phi^3}+\cdots\\
&<1+\frac1{1+\phi}+\frac{1}{\phi+\phi^2}+\frac{1}{\phi+\phi^2+\phi^3}+\cdots\\
&=1+\frac1{1+\phi}+\frac{1}{\phi}\left(\frac1{1+\phi}+\frac{1}{1+\phi+\phi^2}+\cdots\right)\\
&=1+\frac1{1+\phi}+\frac{1}{\phi}(n-1),
\end{align*}
hence
$$\left(1-\frac1\phi\right)n<1+\frac1{1+\phi}-\frac{1}{\phi},$$
and thus
$$n<1+\frac{\frac1{1+\phi}}{1-\frac1\phi}=1+\frac{\phi}{\phi^2-1}=2.$$

As a result, $3<\sqrt 5+1<2n<4$. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i2d=true&i=2Sum%5BDivide%5BDivide%5BSqrt%5B5%5D-1%2C2%5D%2CPower%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5BSqrt%5B5%5D%2B1%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2Ck%5D-1%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D) agrees with our result.

Answer (score 1):

$$2\sum_{k=1}^5\frac{\varphi-1}{\varphi^k-1}=\frac{1105-323\sqrt5}{110}\approx3.48$$
and
$$2\sum_{k=6}^\infty\frac1{1+\varphi+\dots+\varphi^k}<2\sum_{k=6}^\infty\frac1{\varphi^k}=\frac2{\varphi^4}\approx0.29$$
hence
$$\lfloor2n\rfloor+\lceil2n\rceil=7.$$